# How to use JSON data instead of hardcoded data

Tags: android, json, url, video

I'm trying to play a video from vitamio video player for my android app. I can play the video if i directly put the video url into my code. That way i can only play one video at a time.I want to pass the URL data in my JSON to my code so that it reads all of my URLs one by one and play the video when i click the thumbnail of the video (I was able to view the thumbnails)

My VideoBuffer class

```
package com.adaderana.tv.phone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker;
import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer;
import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewBuffer extends Activity implements OnInfoListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener {

  /**
   * TODO: Set the path variable to a streaming video URL or a local media file
   * path.
   */

  private String path = "http://pl.youku.com/playlist/m3u8?ts=1394676342&keyframe=0&vid=XNjU4MTc0Mjky&type=mp4";
  private Uri uri;
  private VideoView mVideoView;
  private ProgressBar pb;
  private TextView downloadRateView, loadRateView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
      return;
    setContentView(R.layout.videobuffer);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.buffer);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.probar);

    downloadRateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.download_rate);
    loadRateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.load_rate);
    if (path == "") {
      // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
      Toast.makeText(
          VideoViewBuffer.this,
          "Please edit VideoBuffer Activity, and set path"
              + " variable to your media file URL/path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;
    } else {
      /*
       * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
       * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
       */
      uri = Uri.parse(path);
      mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
      mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
      mVideoView.requestFocus();
      mVideoView.setOnInfoListener(this);
      mVideoView.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
      mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          // optional need Vitamio 4.0
          mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
      });
    }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    switch (what) {
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
      if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
        mVideoView.pause();
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        downloadRateView.setText("");
        loadRateView.setText("");
        downloadRateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadRateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      }
      break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
      mVideoView.start();
      pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      downloadRateView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      loadRateView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_DOWNLOAD_RATE_CHANGED:
      downloadRateView.setText("" + extra + "kb/s" + "  ");
      break;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    loadRateView.setText(percent + "%");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply read json then I suggest using [google gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). This way you can quickly turn your java objects into json and vice versa. To quickly preapare json structure I recommend using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)